# TypeError: ("cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [4] of <class 'int'>", 'occurred at index 1')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The below code is working fine when I tried to load the data from a CSV File, but it gives an error for a text file as:

> TypeError: ("cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [4] of ", 'occurred at index 1')

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Reading Input File and converting into dataframe

input_data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\py\\Input_Data.txt",delimiter =',') 
input_data_df=pd.DataFrame(input_data)


#Reading Reference File and converting into dataframe

reference_data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\py\\Reference_Data.txt",delimiter =',') 
reference_data_df=pd.DataFrame(reference_data)



#Merging files based on unique Columns

Input_Reference_merge= pd.merge(input_data_df, reference_data_df, on=['emp_id', 'emp_name'])
print(Input_Reference_merge)


# Get the index where jan starts
months_index_start = input_data_df.columns.get_loc("jan")

# Calculate the total salary for each row according to the months_worked column

Input_Reference_merge["total_sal"] = Input_Reference_merge.apply(lambda x : x[months_index_start : months_index_start + x["months_worked"]].sum(), axis = 1)
print(Input_Reference_merge)
```

Below is the data set that I am using.

**File Input_Data:**

```
  emp_id emp_name  months_worked  total_sal   jan  feb      mar  apr  may  \
0       1      aaa              4        NaN  2000    1      2.0    3  4.0   
1       2      bbb              3        NaN     1    2      NaN    4  5.0   
2       3      bbb              7        NaN     1    2  34343.0    4  NaN   
3       4      bbb             12        NaN     1    2  33434.0    4  5.0   

      jun  jul      aug   sep   oct      nov   dec  
0  5555.0  NaN  74343.0     8     9     10.0   NaN  
1   643.0  7.0      NaN  9343    10  13431.0  12.0  
2  6343.0  7.0      NaN     9  1043     11.0  12.0  
3     NaN  7.0      8.0     9     1      NaN  12.0
```

**File Reference_Data:**

```
 emp_id emp_name  months_worked
0       1      aaa              4
1       2      bbb              3
2       3      bbb              7
3       4      bbb             12
```

Comment: `input_data_df=pd.DataFrame(input_data)` This operation is redundant, input_data is already a pandas DataFrame